# Brief application error during/post deployment to Heroku

Tags: heroku

When we are deploying new code to Heroku we are often finding the first request (or couple) to hit get an application error back. After that everything runs fine.

They appear to be request timeouts:

```
2012-06-19T21:54:42+00:00 heroku[router]: Error H12 (Request timeout) -> GET www.mydomain.com/ dyno=web.2 queue= wait= service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0
```

We are using 'unicorn' with 3 processes if that has any possible connection (yes I should probably just run a test myself, but since it's intermittent and hard to pin down I'm hoping others have seen this.). Perhaps increasing the unicorn timeout value will help avoid this but I'm wondering if there is a way to deploy that doesn't result in such large delayed responses after deployment for the first few clients.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed there is such a way to get deploy that may avoid this problem. You can use the Heroku [preboot labs feature](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/labs-preboot/).

Also check out this [Dev Center article on dealing with H12 request timeouts](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/request-timeout).

Comment: I've actually used this with Unicorn and unless something has changed the problem is not necessarily addressed by it. We still had the problem, largely due to a slow startup time. In the end switching back to Thin addressed it for us.